# Chopper FET as a Preamp

Tags: analog, fet

I have a small kit whose [schematic is here](https://vakits.com/sites/default/files/Guitar2%20Rev%20E.pdf),  it has an LM386 (or equivalent) with an FET preamp stage.

The FET went bad, and in searching for a replacement for the now obsolete part, I found that the [datasheet for that FET (2N5638)]https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N5638-D.PDF) says it's a chopper.

Is there an advantage to using a chopper FET over a boring JFET in a low-level analog preamp stage?

Schematic:

[image]

Comment: a "chopper FET" isn't a specific type of FET; it's just a JFET that the manufacturer claims is good for use in chopper circuits.

Comment: When trying to find a stock equivalent. for an obsolete part here , look at Idss @ Vds and Cin and notice 50mA is not stocked , perhaps 2 in parallel with Idss @ 25 mA is possible with low Cin and get the one with dual Nch

Comment: It seems the 2N5638 is IDSS= 50mA @ 20V but 20mA @ 5V which has many equivalents. But your question is about JFET OA's , So for this application JFET OA's  need to bias at Vcc/2  due to Vcm limits ,so a single FET is simpler but a JFET OA is better. http://www.ti.com/product/lf356?qgpn=lf356

Comment: For more details on OA's read here https://www.ti.com/lit/eb/slyt701/slyt701.pdf